# Python LXML.HMTL Xpath Return Empty List

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml, lxml.html

**Problem:**

- The `date_list` is an empty list.
- Should not be empty because list length should equal list length of `oct` and `filing_type_list`.

**What I have done:**

1. searched for typos.
2. tried different companies (example is of REXAHN PHARMACEUTICALS, INC).
3. used different words for the Xpath argument.

**Code:**

```
filing_dates_pg = requests.get('http://csuite.xbrl.us/php/dispatch.php?Task=xbrlValues&Element=NetCashProvidedByUsedInOperatingActivitiesContinuingOperations&CIK=0001228627&Ultimus=true&DimReqd=false&API_Key=xxxx')
# The URL easiest to read in FIREFOX Browser.

Datestree = html.fromstring(filing_dates_pg.text)
date_list = Datestree.xpath('//periodStart/text()')
filing_type_list = Datestree.xpath('//period/text()')
ocf = Datestree.xpath('//amount/text()')

print ocf                # Works, list matches data in URL page
print filing_type_list   # Works
print type(date_list) 
print date_list          # Does NOT work
```

**Output**

```
['-2977634', '-4566843', '-5146845', '-6986598', '-53917328', '-2425835', '-55897199', '-7490595', '-57546899', '-10651611', '-58620377', '-15530306', '-60171904', '-1916510', '-62675625', '-3896381', '-64356343', '-5546081', '-66605233', '-6619559', '-69181840', '-1551527', '-4055248', '-5735966', '-7984856', '-11041211', '-2576607', '-4038817', '-5527773', '-8441718', '-8129391', '-12944191']
['1H', '3QCUM', 'Y', 'Y', '2001-03-19 - 2012-04-01', '1Q', '2001-03-19 - 2012-07-01', '1H', '2001-03-19 - 2012-10-01', '3QCUM', '2001-03-19 - 2013-01-01', 'Y', '2001-03-19 - 2013-04-01', '1Q', '2001-03-19 - 2013-07-01', '1H', '2001-03-19 - 2013-10-01', '3QCUM', '2001-03-19 - 2014-01-01', 'Y', '2001-03-19 - 2014-04-01', '1Q', '1H', '3QCUM', 'Y', 'Y', '1Q', '1Q', '1H', '1H', '3QCUM', '3QCUM']
<type 'list'>
[]
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 1 elements
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're using `lxml.html.fromstring` instead of `lxml.etree.fromstring`.

Use `lxml.etree.fromstring`. Otherwise, you need to specify `//periodstart/text()` xpath expression (all lowercase) because in HTML tag name is case-insensitive.

```
from lxml import etree

...

Datestree = etree.fromstring(filing_dates_pg.text)
```

Comment: I tested this should be the answer!!

Comment: Thx, Falsetru. I went with the lower case solution.

Answer (score 0):

I also face this problem during implementation.

During parsing `html.fromstring` convert tag name ans also attribute name to small case

use like following:

```
>> Datestree.xpath('//periodstart//text()')
```

or also suggested by falsetru use `etree`